# git show-branch not outputting the full revision history?

Tags: git

I can't figure out why git show-branch isn't giving me the same full history that git log --graph shows me. Why would the following discrepancy occur?

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --date-order
*   786c9bd Merge branch 'master' into testbr
|\  
* | dda9989 ch2 to couch
* | 05d0851 chg 1 to couch
| * 3df86c2 change 1 to tv
| * 900ad58 added tv
|/  
* 76352a8 mess
$ git show-branch
! [master] change 1 to tv
 * [testbr] Merge branch 'master' into testbr
--
 - [testbr] Merge branch 'master' into testbr
+* [master] change 1 to tv
```

Further, if I create a new branch (see below), then git show-branch gives the output I expect.

```
$ git branch foo testbr~3
$ git show-branch
! [foo] mess
 ! [master] change 1 to tv
  * [testbr] Merge branch 'master' into testbr
---
  - [testbr] Merge branch 'master' into testbr
 +* [master] change 1 to tv
 +* [master^] added tv
  * [testbr^] ch2 to couch
  * [testbr~2] chg 1 to couch
++* [foo] mess
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), [`git show-branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html) only shows:

- *branches* (`HEAD` that is '`*`' and `non-HEAD`: '`!`' which have a relation with HEAD)
- commits from branches linked to HEAD (below the '`--`'):

  - '`*`' commits from `HEAD` branch
  - '`+`' commits from `non-HEAD` branches
  - '`*+`' commits from `non-HEAD` branches also part of `HEAD` branch
  - '`-`' merge commits

and their commits), not *all* commits.

The fact that your second example looks like the initial `git log` only means that those commits displayed in the second show-branch are linked to the `HEAD` branch, making them close of a classic commit graph (which git log produces)